# How do I mount a CloneCD .img file?

Tags: mount, iso

CloneCD is proprietary. I have a bunch of images that were created with in. Inside of the `.CCD` file it says.

```
[CloneCD]
Version=3
```

How do I mount this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To mount a `.ccd` file created with CloneCD, first translate the file to an `.iso` file,

```
ccd2iso MyImage.img MyImage.iso
```

Then mount the `.iso` file,

```
sudo mkdir /tmp/disk
mount -o loop -t iso9660 ./MyImage.iso /tmp/disk/
```

Comment: Important note: [ccd2iso will not handle a `.sub` file if it exists](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ccd2iso.1.html). The `.iso` may or may not work without this data, but the result is in no way a faithful copy of what was in the `.ccd/.sub/.img` combo.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases `ccd2iso` wont work. Try `acetoneiso`.

```
$ sudo apt install acetoneiso
```